# Finding blocks in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a question about Netlogo. 
Is there any smart way how to find block of patches (in my case, I need to find block of three patches with yellow color => more precisely, I need to find row or column with three yellow patches next to each other). 
Is there any Netlogo function I could use or is it neccessary to use loops and work as I would with two-dimensional array?n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ask patches` you can loop over all patches. Further a condition can be applied to the `ask` statement by using `with`. So you are looping over all the patches meeting that condition. Here I just put the x and y coordinates of the patches in a list which you can then further process.

```
let yellow_patches []
ask patches with [pcolor = yellow] [
    set yellow_patches lput [pxcor pycor] yellow_patches
]
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. I am sorry for late reaction.

Comment: thanks. Please accept as answer and/or give a vote up :)

Answer (score 1):

[blckbird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4139024/blckbird) is correct, if you want you can extract all coordinates of yellow patches and process those coordinates to figure out which patches are adjacent.

If all you need is to know where your rows or columns of threes are, however, you could also get all the yellow patches to check the color of neighboring patches and tell you if a row or column is formed. For an example, see the code below.

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  ask n-of 150 patches [
    set pcolor yellow 
  ]

end

to find-threes

  ;; for rows
  ask patches with [ pcolor = yellow ] [
    if ( [pcolor] of patch-at 1 0 = yellow ) and ( [pcolor] of patch-at -1 0 = yellow ) [
      ;; do whatever you need
      set pcolor pcolor - 3
      show ("I am the center of a row of three")
    ]
  ]

  ;; for columns
  ask patches with [ pcolor = yellow ] [
    if ( [pcolor] of patch-at 0 1 = yellow ) and ( [pcolor] of patch-at 0 -1 = yellow ) [
      ;; do whatever you need
      set pcolor pcolor - 3
      show ("I am the center of a column of three")
    ]
  ]

end
```

Comment: Hello, I am sorry for late reaction, your answer is great and realy helpful. Thank you